# SQL Server fastest way to change data types on large tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We need to change the data type of about 10 primary keys in our db from `numeric(19,0)` to bigint.  On the smaller tables a simple update of the datatype works just fine but on the larger tables (60-70 million rows) it takes a considerable amount of time.

What is the fastest way to achieve this, preferably without locking the database.

I've written a script that generates the following (which I believe I got from a different SO post)

```
--Add a new temporary column to store the changed value.
ALTER TABLE query_log ADD id_bigint bigint NULL;
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_query_log_id_bigint ON query_log (id_bigint)
INCLUDE (id); -- the include only works on SQL 2008 and up
-- This index may help or hurt performance, I'm not sure... :)

GO

declare @count int
declare @iteration int
declare @progress int
set @iteration = 0
set @progress = 0

select @count = COUNT(*) from query_log
RAISERROR ('Processing %d records', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT

-- Update the table in batches of 10000 at a time
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN 

   UPDATE X -- Updating a derived table only works on SQL 2005 and up
   SET X.id_bigint = id
   FROM (
      SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM query_log WHERE id_bigint IS NULL
   ) X;
   IF @@RowCount = 0 BREAK;
   set @iteration = @iteration + 1
   set @progress = @iteration * 10000
   RAISERROR ('processed %d of %d records', 0, 1, @progress, @count) WITH NOWAIT
END;
GO

--kill the pkey on the old column
ALTER TABLE query_log
DROP CONSTRAINT PK__query_log__53833672
GO

BEGIN TRAN; -- now do as *little* work as possible in this blocking transaction
UPDATE T -- catch any updates that happened after we touched the row
SET T.id_bigint = T.id
FROM query_log T WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
WHERE T.id_bigint <> T.id;
-- The lock hints ensure everyone is blocked until we do the switcheroo

EXEC sp_rename 'query_log.id', 'id_numeric';
EXEC sp_rename 'query_log.id_bigint', 'id';
COMMIT TRAN;
GO

DROP INDEX IX_query_log_id_bigint ON query_log;    
GO

ALTER TABLE query_log ALTER COLUMN id bigint NOT NULL;
GO

/*
ALTER TABLE query_log DROP COLUMN id_numeric;
GO
*/

ALTER TABLE query_log
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_query_log PRIMARY KEY (id)
GO
```

This works very well for the smaller tables but is extremely slow going for the very large tables.

Note this is in preparation for a migration to Postgres and the EnterpriseDB Migration toolkit doesn't seem to understand the numeric(19,0) datatype

Answer (score 1):

If is not possible to change a primary key without locking.  The fastest way with the least impact is to create a new table with the new columns and primary keys without foreign keys and indexes.  Then batch insert blocks of data in sequential order relative to their primary key(s).  When that is finished, add your indexes, then foreign keys back.  Finally, drop or rename the old table and rename your new table to the systems expected table name.

In practice your approach will have to vary based on how many records are inserted, updated, and/or deleted.  If you're only inserting then you can perform the initial load, and top of the table just before your swap.

This approach should provide the fastest migration, minimal logs, and very little fragmentation on your table and indexes.

You have to remember that every time you modify a record, the data is being modified, indexes are being modified, and foreign keys are being checked.  All within one implicit or explicit transaction.  The table and/or row(s) will be locked while all changes are made.  Even if your database is set to simple logging, the server will still write all changes to the log files.  Updates actually are a delete paired with an insert so it is not possible to prevent fragmentation during any other process.

Comment: Although definitely faster, I would be cautious doing it this way and then only when you are confident no changes are being made to the table. Unless you have your isolation level set to Serializable (which will essentially lock the table) you will not be guaranteed to get new records (phantom records) or updates to records after then have already been read (non-repeatable reads). Regardless, modifying a table takes a schema lock on the table only and will not lock the database.